# Integration Services: cannot change the Authentication from Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to connect to Integration Services and I need to switch to "SQL Server Authentication" mode but it is disabled by default. For connecting to Database Engine, this option is working fine but it is not working for Integration Services. Please advice how we can enable it?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe you can only access this service under a windows account. It doesn't have a user/password type security mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but we wouldn't be able to access Integration Services using any SQL authentication. 
I believe, Its a security feature.